# Check the access condition on a MIFARE Ultralight page

Tags: nfc, mifare

How to check whether the page is writable on a Mifare Ultralight tag?
Following the example
NFC TagInfo
NFC Research Lab
The menu "Access Conditions"
Page1..Page15
read-only/writable(factory locked/locked)/reserved/lock bits

Comment: Your question doesnt make much sense. Fix your links for a start

Comment: hi , i want to know how to check whether the page is writable on a Mifare Ultralight access conditions page for write data.Did you have any ideia thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consult the MIFARE Ultralight datasheet, available at http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF0ICU1.pdf
The bits of the 2 lock bytes in page 0x02 determine which page can be written, see page 12 of the linked datasheet above.

Comment: I have page 2 hex:
dd48f77f
In this case,
Page 3 (OTP) - writable (locked)
Page 15 (data) - writable (locked)

How to disassemble a hex on page 2?